# Python script drops into pdb without reason

Tags: python, ipython, pdb

I have a python function that I'm calling from inside an iPython session.

In a very specific situation, in which a conditional in a certain line comes out as True, the script consistently drops into a pdb debug mode.

There is no trace or any other indication of a problem with the code, and as soon as I type `c` to continue, the code continues perfectly well.

The script doesn't include any `import pdb` not to mention a `set_trace()`...

Any ideas what could account for this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your ipython config it automatically goes into PDB if an exception is raised.

Comment: Yes, I have this in my ipython config, but, as I wrote, there is no evidence for any exception being raised in this case.

Comment: Also, I disabled the automatic pdb option of ipython, and the same behavior persists.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` line in the code after all, which I missed due to source control issues.